# Marshalling Function Pointers with .NET 7 LibraryImport

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to implement some P/Invoke code using the new `LibraryImport` attribute, as opposed to the old `DllImport`. Specifically, I am trying to marshal a [`WNDCLASSEXW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) struct for use in [`RegisterClassEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexa).

Here is a simplified, shortened version of my managed implementation of `WNDCLASSEXW`:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct WindowClass
{
    private uint StructSize;
    public WindowClassStyle Style;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public Win32API.WindowProcedure? WindowProcedure;
    private int ClassAdditionalBytes;
    private int WindowAdditionalBytes;
    public IntPtr Instance;
    public IntPtr Icon;
    public IntPtr Cursor;
    public IntPtr BackgroundBrush;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string? ClassMenuResourceName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string? ClassName;
    public IntPtr SmallIcon;
}
```

And my definition of `Win32API.WindowProcedure`:

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate nint WindowProcedure(IntPtr windowHandle, MessageID messageID, nuint wParam, nint lParam);
```

And finally my definition of `RegisterClassEx`:

```cs
[LibraryImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "RegisterClassExW")]
public static partial ushort RegisterClassEx(in WindowClass classDefinition);
```

However, this results in the error:

> Error SYSLIB1051: The type 'xxx.WindowClass' is not supported by source-generated P/Invokes. The generated source will not handle marshalling of parameter 'classDefinition'.

Therefore I believe I require custom marshalling for the `WindowClass` struct.

However, with this system being relatively new, I'm having difficulty finding good guidance on how to do this correctly and optimally. Previously, `DllImport` would magically marshal most types with little guidance, but `LibraryImport` appears to require more information, and be a bit stricter.

I could circumvent the problem by changing the type to `IntPtr` and requiring conversion of the `delegate` to `IntPtr` elsewhere in the program, but I would much prefer to do it as close to the managed/unmanaged boundary as possible and keep the structs and exposed native functions usable with more descriptive types.

Some of the resources I have found while searching:

- [The old P/Invoke documentation regarding delegates/function pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-a-delegate-as-a-callback-method)
- [The new information regarding CustomMarshaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/tutorial-custom-marshaller)
- [The design documentation for the new source generator-based system](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/libraries/LibraryImportGenerator/UserTypeMarshallingV2.md)

**Primary Question:** How do I correctly implement custom marshalling for my WNDPROC and the LP(C)WSTRs?

**Question 2:**
I would prefer to use a `readonly struct`, and turn all of the members into `{ get; init; }` properties instead of fields, due to the nicer semantics. However I've noticed that the `MarshalAs` attribute cannot be applied to properties. Is there a good way to both use `readonly struct`s with properties, while also providing the necessary information to ensure everything gets marshalled in/out correctly? Specifically for more complex types such as `string? <-> LPCWSTR`, `delegate? <-> void*`, and other such types I may encounter.

**Bonus Question:**
It appears that `LibraryImport` de-emphasizes the importance of specifying the correct calling convention. It's no longer part of the main attribute like `DllImport`, instead using a secondary attribute that looks like this: `[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvStdcall) })]` which frankly looks terrible. Is specifying calling convention necessary or beneficial now?

Comment: In the struct, define `ClassMenuResourceName` and `ClassName` as `unsafe char*` instead of `string`, define `WindowProcedure` as an `IntPtr`, and use  `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<Win32API.WindowProcedure>(YourProc)` to set it in the struct.

Comment: @SimonMourier I addressed this in the post, and mentioned I don't want to expose these low-level types in these structs if I can avoid it. It sounds however like the solution would be to make a `CustomMarshaller` that converts this managed struct into an internal-only native one with `IntPtr` and `char*` members. I will try this and respond with results later.

Comment: You're looking for guidance, LibraryImport is by design unsafe and quite different than DllImport and friend attributes, based on simple code looking more like C/C++. Writing a custom marshaler for this struct is not needed.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm mainly using `LibraryImport` because it, unlike `DllImport`, is described as working with AOT compilation. Since this is a library however, I wish to avoid unsafe structs being exposed directly to other code.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working with custom marshaling. While Simon's advice of changing the struct to contain the native types makes sense in the general case, in my case it doesn't, as these will be exposed for others to use.

The answer might be different for faster, more frequently called methods, but in this case registering a class and creating a window is inherently quite an expensive operation, so the added overhead of copying data to/from a different struct isn't worth any concern.

The marshaler was implemented like this:

```cs
[CustomMarshaller(typeof(WindowClass), MarshalMode.UnmanagedToManagedIn, typeof(WindowClassMarshaler))]
[CustomMarshaller(typeof(WindowClass), MarshalMode.ManagedToUnmanagedIn, typeof(ManagedToUnmanagedIn))]
internal static unsafe class WindowClassMarshaler
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal unsafe struct WindowClassUnmanaged
    {
        public uint StructSize;
        public uint Style;
        public IntPtr WindowProcedure;
        public int ClassAdditionalBytes;
        public int WindowAdditionalBytes;
        public IntPtr Instance;
        public IntPtr Icon;
        public IntPtr Cursor;
        public IntPtr BackgroundBrush;
        public char* ClassMenuResourceName;
        public char* ClassName;
        public IntPtr SmallIcon;
    }

    internal static unsafe WindowClass ConvertToManaged(WindowClassUnmanaged unmanaged)
    {
        return new()
        {
            WindowProcedure = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<Win32API.WindowProcedure>(unmanaged.WindowProcedure),
            ClassMenuResourceName = MarshalHelpers.Win32WideCharArrToString(unmanaged.ClassMenuResourceName),
            ClassName = MarshalHelpers.Win32WideCharArrToString(unmanaged.ClassName),
            // (remainder omitted, just simple copies)
        };
    }

    internal unsafe ref struct ManagedToUnmanagedIn
    {
        public static int BufferSize => sizeof(WindowClassUnmanaged);

        private byte* UnmanagedBufferStruct;
        private char* UnmanagedStrResourceName, UnmanagedStrClassName;

        public void FromManaged(WindowClass managed, Span<byte> buffer)
        {
            IntPtr WindowProcedure = (managed.WindowProcedure == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(managed.WindowProcedure);
            this.UnmanagedStrResourceName = (managed.ClassMenuResourceName == null) ? null : (char*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(managed.ClassMenuResourceName);
            this.UnmanagedStrClassName = (managed.ClassName == null) ? null : (char*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(managed.ClassName);

            WindowClassUnmanaged Result = new()
            {
                WindowProcedure = WindowProcedure,
                ClassMenuResourceName = this.UnmanagedStrResourceName,
                ClassName = this.UnmanagedStrClassName,
                // (remainder omitted, just simple copies)
            };

            Span<byte> ResultByteView = MemoryMarshal.Cast<WindowClassUnmanaged, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref Result, 1));
            Debug.Assert(buffer.Length >= ResultByteView.Length, "Target buffer isn't large enough to hold the struct data.");
            ResultByteView.CopyTo(buffer);

            this.UnmanagedBufferStruct = (byte*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer));
        }

        public byte* ToUnmanaged() => this.UnmanagedBufferStruct;

        public void Free()
        {
            if (this.UnmanagedStrResourceName != null)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal((nint)this.UnmanagedStrResourceName);
                this.UnmanagedStrResourceName = null;
            }
            if (this.UnmanagedStrClassName != null)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal((nint)this.UnmanagedStrClassName);
                this.UnmanagedStrClassName = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this helper function to convert a Win32 `LP(C)WSTR` into a regular .NET `string`:

```cs
public static unsafe string? Win32WideCharArrToString(char* unmanagedArr)
{
    if (unmanagedArr == null) { return null; }
    int Length = 0;
    while (*(unmanagedArr + Length) != 0x0000) { Length++; }
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString((byte*)unmanagedArr, Length * sizeof(char));
}
```

The nicer `WindowClass` struct is pretty much the same as before, except readonly, and with all elements being `{ get; init; }`. The `MarshalAs` attributes on members are no longer required, as the custom marshaling handles everything.

Finally, the actual extern function now looks like this:

```cs
[LibraryImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "RegisterClassExW")]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvStdcall) })]
public static partial ushort RegisterClassEx([MarshalUsing(typeof(WindowClassMarshaler))] WindowClass classDefinition);
```

Note that this has been corrected. Previously I used the `in` keyword on the parameter, but this causes it to pass a pointer to the pointer to the struct data, which is an extra level of indirection that will cause the code to fail. Above is the updated version that works correctly.

I've tested and verified this works both in regular publish modes, as well as with AOT compilation, which was the reason for using `LibraryImport` in this case.

My bonus question still stands however, is there any benefit in specifying stdcall using `UnmanagedCallConv`?

Comment: Why are you also defining `UnmanagedToManagedIn`? This API only goes from managed to unmanaged.

Comment: @silkfire Hmm, good question. I guess I could say I wrote that just to get some practice or have the code available in case it's needed for a different API call, but I think the real answer is I wasn't thinking too much and just writing :)